# How to align all left floated elements in center of their parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.container{width:50%;padding:10px;box-sizing:border-box;background-color:#00FF00;}
.container::after {content: ''; display: table; clear: both;}
.child{width:100px;height:30px;line-height:30px;text-align:center;border-radius:2px;background-color:#FFFF00;float:left;margin:2px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">First</div>
  <div class="child">Second</div>
  <div class="child">Third</div>
  <div class="child">Fourth</div>
</div>
```

I want to align the content of `.container` in center without using property `display: inline-block;` on `.child`.

Comment: Why is `inline-block` not an option?

Comment: The first rule of centering is **don't use floats**.

Comment: There is no reason to use `float` unless you actually want them left or right. If you don't...don't use float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here : **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/avu5psue/2/)**

EDITED : use `display:flex` with `justify-content:center` on the `.sub-container` and `display:inline-block` to `.child`

or you could use `float:left` on `.child` , it still works. but i suggest you don't use float when you want to center smth

code :

```css
.child
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  display:inline-block;
}

.sub-container
{
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

let me know if this was what you were looking for

Comment: well in media query, change also the `display:flex` to `display:block`

Answer (score 0):

Add to `.main-container { margin: 0 auto; display: table; }` and remove `width:100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:
Add margin 50% - half the width of the container. Just a disclaimer: this is not supported in some of the browsers.

```css
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50px);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  float: left;
}
```